# Upgrading from Web API RC to Web API RTM

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have seen that yesterday Web API RTM has been released by Microsoft. 
However I can't seem to find any log about what has changed from RC to RTM and any tips on what has changed.

We have a service that's ready for production next week, and I am not sure whether to roll with RC or upgrade to RTM this late in the project. What value does it add?

Thanks
Ubal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official release notes can be [found here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253817) at www.asp.net.

As @Aliostad kindly mentioned, I wrote an [overview post](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/asp-net-web-api-is-released-whats-new-in-web-api-rtm-and-how-to-use-it/) highlighting what's changing and including some code samples and other references.

Henrik also wrote a nice [overview post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/15/asp-net-web-api-released-and-a-preview-of-what-s-next.aspx) - and that one's also focused on the preview for the out-of-band functionalities available as NuGet packages (OData, tracing, Help page, and a formatting library for Win8).

If you ask whether you should upgrade - obviously yes. There aren't many breaking changes so it should be rather painless, and you get a mature, production-deployable product. It's well worth it imho.